# Como posso imprimir meus resultados em um arquivo de texto?

Tags: python-3.x, matemática, sistema-de-arquivos, visão-computacional, princípios-de-programação

Bom, eu preciso resolver alguns sistemas lineares por meio do método de Jacobi usando a programação em Python 3.8, fiz o código (que vou deixar logo abaixo), porém não consigo fazer um arquivo de impressão que guarde meus resultados de forma organizada. Meus objetivos são:

1. Criar uma pasta e nela um arquivo com a função de Jacobi
2. De um outro arquivo 'chamar' essa função para resolver todos os sistemas lineares que estarão lá
3. Imprimir esses resultados de forma organizada, como a figura abaixo
   [image: Modelo de como devem ser as impressões]

---

```
import numpy as np
n = 3
A = np.array([(10.0, 3, -2), (2.0, 8, -1), (1.0, 1, 5)])
b = np.array([(57.0), (20.0), (-4.0)])
Toler = 1.0000e-05
IterMax = 50
x = np.zeros((n, 1))
v = np.zeros((n, 1))
Iter = 0
CondErro = 0
for i in range(n):
    r = (1/A[i, i])
    for j in range(n):
        if i != j:
            A[i, j] *= r
    b[i] *= r
    x[i] = b[i]
Iter = 0
while True:
    Iter += 1
    for i in range(n):
        soma = 0
        for j in range(n):
            if i != j:
                soma += A[i, j] * x[j]
        v[i] = b[i] - soma
    NormaNum = 0
    NormaDen = 0
    for i in range(n):
        t = abs(v[i]-x[i])
        if t > NormaNum:
            NormaNum = t
        if abs(v[i]) > NormaDen:
            NormaDen = abs(v[i])
        x[i] = v[i]
    NormaRel = (NormaNum / NormaDen)
    print(f'{Iter}{x}{NormaRel}')
    if NormaRel <= Toler or Iter >= IterMax:
        break
if NormaRel <= Toler:
    CondErro = 0
else:
    CondErro = 1
```

Comment: Não seria mais simples apenas exibir da maneira comum e quando quiser redirecionar a saída padrão para um arquivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
buf = "" # cria um buffer para substituir o stdout

buf += "string" # fazer isso ao invés de print("string")

with open("filename", "w") as f:
    f.write(buf)
```

Ou criar outro arquivo e fazer isso:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.run(["python3", "jacobi.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
with open("filename", "wb") as f:
    f.write(p.stdout)
```

Comment: Eu não consegui entender muito bem, o que eu preciso aprender para poder entender seu código e coloca-lo em prática na minha situação ?

deixa eu colocar um exemplo mais simples pra ver se você pode me ajudar com mais detalhes
Suponha no arquivo1.py:
def soma(a, b)
      soma = a + b
      return soma
suponha no arquivo 2:
import arquivo1
a = 3
b = 5
arquivo1.soma(a, b)

>> 8

Dito isto eu gostaria de aprender a criar um arquivo .txt que nele contivesse o seguinte

O valor da primeira parcela a foi 3
O valor da segunda parcela foi 5 
e portanto a soma vale 8.

Comment: Acho que seria bom você pesquisar por arquivos em Python, e também PIPEs.

Comment: Eu pesquisei bastante sobre como escrever e ler arquivos em python, função .read e .write, vou pesquisar este PIPE